# How do I find resistor values for an LSTTL to ECL interface?

Tags: mosfet, ttl

[image: LSTTL to ECL]

- LSTTL is a 74LS10 three input NAND gate
- ECL levels are -0.75 volts and -1.55 volts
- Supply voltages are +5 volts and -5.2 volts

I am really not sure how to proceed with this. I've tried setting the output of the LSTTL to the V[OH] and V[OL] given in the data sheet but got nowhere useful.

Comment: IIRC, one trick was to power the TTL logic between the -5.2V and 0V rails (instead of GND and +5V) with an TTL output pull-up to 0V, then directly connect TTL outputs to ECL inputs.

Comment: which? PECL
Vcc = +5 V
LVPECL
Vcc = +2.5 V
LVPECL
Vcc = +3.3 V
LVNECL
Vee = −3.3 V
NECL
Vee  = −4.5 to −5.2 V

Comment: @Tony, he gave the input voltage levels and showed a -5.2 V supply. I think that's enough to answer your question.

Comment: then why not use a quad converter MC10H424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ignore R1 for now. It doesn't do anything except make sure the circuit can source current when the TTL gate is in the low state.

Now it looks like you have two equations and two unknowns:

$$-5.2 + \frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}(V_{ol}-(-5.2)) = V_{il}$$

$$-5.2 + \frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}(V_{oh}-(-5.2)) = V_{ih}$$

where \$V_{ol}\$ and \$V_{oh}\$ are the output voltages of the driving gate and \$V_{il}\$ and \$V_{ih}\$ are the input voltages you want to generate at the receiving gate.

But note that your unknowns (R2 and R3) appear in the same combination in both equations: \$\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}\$, so really there's just one unknown --- the ratio \$R_3/R_2\$.

In order to have freedom to get whatever \$V_{ih}\$ and \$V_{il}\$ you want (within reason) you'll have to open up another degree of freedom. For example, if you could adjust the pull-down voltage (currently -5.2 V), you would be able to do this.

One way you might do this is by putting some combination of diodes between R3 and the ECL circuit's VEE.

Another option might be getting rid of R1 and using the fact the TTL gate can't source current in the low state to your advantage. A third resistor from the TTL output to ground could help here.

Answer (score 0):

The only voltage you can trust out of a 74LS10 is the logic-low, probably 0.2 volts with the need to handle the current thru R1 pullup. R1 is there, to ensure the TTL output is above the minimum value (+2.4v) and thus the TTL output has no effect on the ECL input-logic-high.

The input to ECL is tolerant of the logic-low, because the diffpair current is being steered. Once the tail current is steered, taking the input even lower will affect speed of switching (gotta change the E_B charge) but not affect the output logic-levels.

The input to ECL is intolerant of sloppy logic-high, because of risk of saturation of the diffpair. To precisely generate this -0.75 volts, you need stable resistors and STABLE RAILS. And a circuit designed to ignore the TTL logic-high output.

To preserve speed, I'd use a 5pF cap from TTL out to ECL in; just like a scope probe gets compensated to maintain flat pulse response (R1*C1 = R2*C2), you have that same responsibility here. Somewhere between 2pf and 10pF.

You've not mentioned the input current of the ECL gate. And some ECL gates have internal 50Kohm pulldowns (to -5.2v) to prevent floating bases. What current must this level-translator provide into the ECL gate?

Thus we have this circuit(R values are uncertain):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo0xTS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>